# How would I compare a text file with multiple other files in bash

Tags: bash

Hi guys what I have is several text files (all in a single directory) in this format:

```
server1.txt  
Jar file 1 : md5sum : size  
Jar file 2 : md5sum : size  
Jar file 3 : md5sum : size  
etc
```

So what I would like to do is compare one of these files against the others in order to come up with a list of `jar` names that appear in the master text file but do not appear in the other files. I will need to have the data arranged so that the names of the text files are read to stdout wherever differences are found across all the files.

This is what I have so far, that will read the master text file, and take the required fields from it (the jar name and its corresponding md5sum). A loop then reads all the other text files and places them in an array  before the actual comparison:

`jarListFiles=(*.txt)` #only the required files are in this directory

`( cat ukv01stats.txt | while IFS=: read f1 f2 f3 f4 ; do echo "$f1 - $f2" > temp_ukv01stats.txt;  done < ukv01stats.txt ; for file in ${jarListFiles[@]}; do read f1 f2 f3 f4 ; echo "$f1 - $f2" > temp_$file; done < $file ;  diff temp_ukv01stats.txt $file )`

However, with this I am getting a `bash: 0: ambiguous redirect
diff: missing operand after temp_ukv01stats.txt
diff: Try diff --help' for more information.`

Your help would be greatly appreciated and many thanks in advance for your time in finding a solution.

Comment: Welcome to SO UmairK! Normally SO is a code help service, not a writing service. It's best to ask questions that show what you've tried and/or researched and how it's not working for you and then ask for help.

Comment: Take the files you're comparing sort. Then compare them line by line. We aren't going to write the code for you lol

Comment: I have modified the question and main body that includes the start of a possible solution. Please take another look guys. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NAME
       diff - compare files line by line

SYNOPSIS
       diff [OPTION]... FILES

DESCRIPTION
       Compare FILES line by line.

       Mandatory arguments to long options are mandatory for short options too.

       [...]

       -r, --recursive
              recursively compare any subdirectories found
```

So, `diff -R directory1/ directory2/`.